# Unknown and empty white page suddenly appears from bottom while typing

Tags: react-native

A lot of iOS users (mainly iOS 15, but iOS 14 also) started to report a strange behaviour: while they're typing in the login screen or signup screen, the app became blank.

Watching the videos provided, it seems that a white "something" (like a modal, but not a modal) comes from the bottom at any time they are writing inside text input and cover the full app, so the only thing the user can do it's to kill the app.

It's impossible for us to recreate this behaviour (both on simulator than real devices).
Any idea or any known issue?

react-native version: 0.63.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found:
It's a well-known bug of KeyboardAvoidingView on iOS when user enables "Prefer Cross-Fade Transitions". They just forgot to solve it or, at least, add a warn  on KeyboardAvoidingView documentation.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29974

(thank you Wilson!)